# Disable combo box for opening but keep other events

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, combobox, dom-events

I have an application the does some DOM selection.
when I click on elements they stay marked and application remembers these elements.

In the case of a combobox (drop-down-menu) when I click it, in addition to marking it (as in all other elements) it also opens up the combobox. I want to prevent this from happening.
The way I know to this is by using disable="true". So I figured I can disable the combobox on `mouseOver` and re-enable it on `mouseOut`. However when I do this, it disables all events, thus I can't click on it anymore nor does the `mouseOut` event called.

Is there a way to prevent a combo box from opening without disabling other events such as `onClick` and `mouseOver`?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with your code. The behavior you describe is a little odd. Why would you want to disable something on mouse out? if it's a design effect, why not just place with the classNames?

Comment: I'm not responsible for the application, I am doing DOM element selection on a number of different applications. The reason I want to disable on mouseOver is so that the combobox will not open when I click it, I want to mark it instead, then I want to return the application back to normal, and I use the mouseOut event for this.